# Animating a tip of a banner to wave (like a flag in the wind)

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript, 2d, banner

I currently have a 2D image of a flag, which I've gotten from a client. I'm supposed to create a flash banner out of it, but the tip of the flag needs to "wave in the wind" in the little.

Is there a way to do this in Flash or Actionscript(3.0) without requiring me to draw the tip of the banner in multiple frames?

Answer (score 0):

Divide the flag into triangles and draw it using `Graphics.drawTriangles`. Then animate the vertices programmatically. See [this link](http://www.3dtutorialzone.com/tutorial?id=41) for a conceptual overview (the link is about 3D modelling and animating a flag, but it's the same concept).